# React - Array de Checkbox e useState

Tags: array, react, checkbox

Eu tenho uma função no React que tem tem um array:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
    
function profileMessages () {
const messages = [
        {
            label: "a",
            id: "a",
            name: "a",
            checked: true
        },
        {
            label: "b",
            id: "b",
            name: "b",
            checked: true
        },
        {
            label: "c",
            id: "c",
            name: "c",
            checked: true
        },

       const [ checked, setChecked ] = useState( [] );

return (
    { messages.map( ( item, index ) => (
    <div key={ index } >
    <input id={ item.id } name={ item.name } value={ item.checked } type="checkbox" />
    <label htmlFor={ item.id } >
    <p className='text-black'>{ item.label }</p>
    <button onClick?? />
    </div> ) ) }
)
```

A ideia é que o usuário clique no botão e altere o valor do checked do checkbox do array messages. Tentei criar diversas funções onClick, mas nada deu certo. Na última tentativa eu fiz o seguinte:

```
const clickCheck= ( item, index ) => {
        let newChecked = item.checked;
        newChecked = !item.checked;
        setChecked( { checked: newChecked } );
    };
```

Mas também não deu certo, não consigo alterar o estado do checked. Alguém poderia me auxiliar nessa função?

Comment: Olá amigo! Tu poderias esclarecer o que tu quiseste dizer com "não deu certo"? Houve algum erro? Qual a mensagem? Ou seria algum comportamento inesperado? Poderias descrever?

Comment: Na verdade, não acontece nada. Sem mensagens de erros, mas também não altera o estado anterior. O estado continua sendo true (que é o estado inicial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe algumas formas de mudar um item contido em um `array`. Nesse exemplo eu utilize o `map` para recriar um novo `array` (porque se não fizer uma nova cópia o `React` não altera porque o dado é imutável) e nessa interação de cada item eu verifique qual dos item foi alterado e altera o `checked` de acordo com o que foi alterado no `click`, o que não foi alterado é copiado da mesma forma. Nessa parte:

```
const newItems = items.map((item) => {
    if (item.id === e.target.id) {
      return {
        ...item, // copia todo o objeto
        checked: e.target.checked // mudar o item que no caso é checked
      }
    }
    return item;
});
```

É sempre bom colocar `name` e `id` nas propriedades dos `input` para que você consiga localizar qual é o item a ser alterado, também vale lembrar que o `id` precisa ser único para dar certo, olha no exemplo:

```js
const messages = [
  {
      label: "a",
      id: "a",
      name: "a",
      checked: true
  },
  {
      label: "b",
      id: "b",
      name: "b",
      checked: true
  },
  {
      label: "c",
      id: "c",
      name: "c",
      checked: true
  }];

function ProfileMessages() {    
    const [ items, setItems ] = React.useState(messages);
    function handleChange(e) {
      const newItems = items.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === e.target.id) {
          return {
            ...item,
            checked: e.target.checked
          }
        }
        return item;
      });
      setItems(newItems);
    }        
    return (
      <div>
        {items && items.map((item, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <input 
            name={item.name}
            id={item.id}
            type="checkbox" 
            checked={item.checked} 
            onChange={handleChange} /> 
            <label htmlFor={item.id}>{item.label}</label>
        </div>))}
      </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render( <ProfileMessages/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

Também coloquei o `array` fora da função para que essa variável não seja recriada sempre, isso nem sempre da para fazer, mas, nesse caso exemplo pode ser feito.

Comment: Sensacional, deu certo! Eu fiquei uns 2 dias quebrando a cabeça. Realmente, o state é imutável e criando uma cópia do array a função alterou o estado. Perfeito, muito obrigado!

Comment: a perseguição na rede que mais morre no cenário da Internet ... que pena! existe um padrão ...